# Multiple repositories, divergent sources

Tags: git, repository

My source code is common across 2 remote repo (one for production and one for backup purpose) and I would like to add a folder specifically on my backup repo and not the other (and be able to get it from this repo on any computer without pushing it on the production repo). Is it possible to do that with git workflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do

1. On the backup repo, create a new branch, say `with_folder`, branching out from the main master branch
2. Make changes to your `with_folder` branch for any changes related to your code in the extra folder.
3. Periodically [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) this branch on `master`

So, your flow becomes like

- `git checkout master && git branch with_folder`
- Work on master branch for changes related to master branch
- `git checkout with_folder && git rebase master` to bring your `with_folder` up to date with code from `master` branch
- Since the branch `with_folder` contains contains changes specific to the folder, there will ***never*** be any `merge`/`rebase` conflicts
- Make changes to the `folder`, commit using `git add folder && git commit -m "msg"`
- Continue working on your master after doing `git checkout master`